# Error: bind EADDRINUSE when hot module replacement enabled in neutrino node

Tags: node.js, neutrino

I'm using [neutrino node.js preset](https://neutrino.js.org/packages/node/) with hot module replacement enabled, here's what I have in `index.js`:

```
import fastify from 'fastify'
import router from './router'

const ft = fastify()

ft.register(router)

// enable hot module replacement
if (module.hot) {
  module.hot.accept()
}

// listen
ft.listen(3000, 'localhost', (err) => {
  if (err) throw err
  console.log(`server listening on ${ft.server.address().port}`)
})
```

When I edit a file, I would got this:

[image]

I'm wondering if it is possible to use hot module replacement like this? Anyone have experience?

Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried using a different port?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using HMR with Node.js, it is a little trickier than with web projects since reloading the top-level file would mean needing to restart the process.

If you take note from the [Neutrino docs on HMR in Node.js](https://neutrino.js.org/packages/node/#hot-module-replacement), you'll see that HMR isn't performed on the top-level `index.js` file, but rather on items that `index.js` imports.

Therefore, you'll want to accept specific things `index.js` imports, and use those from within, instead of trying to reload `index.js` which won't work without restarting the process.

```
if (module.hot) {
  module.hot.accept('./router');
  // Optionally use a function to re-bind functionality
  // after the accept:
  // module.hot.accept('./router', () => /* ... */);
}
```